# How should I change the value to 0 without remove the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-operations

I have a dataframe which contains three rows, and I want to make the amount to 0 for those LeadID? =0 (not a leaddeal). Don't remove them. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks for the help.

#### raw data

```
LeadID  LeadID? Amount
31578    1       $189
17698    1       $187
21891    1       $191
25062    1       $127
25062    0       $127
15133    1       $167
15133    0       $167
14321    1       $122
19148    1       $181
```

#### rows

[image: DataFrame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign values to slices of your dataframe by indexing using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['LeadID?'] == 0, 'Amount'] = '$0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in LeadID(8):
if x == 1:
   x == 0
    break
```

I haven't used Python in a long time but should be something simple like this. I'm also assuming there's only 8 fields. If there's more, add that number, keeping in mind that 0 is the first index.